# How much proof is needed in such paper (Maths related)?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm writing a paper (report) regarding  *Euler's Number* $\space e \space$ (even though he didn't discover it).

Within this paper, I show that:

$${d\over dx} {e^x} = {e^x}$$

**NOTE: ** This is not what the whole paper is about.

However, the proof uses the fact that:

$$\space {d\over dx}\ln f(x) = {f'(x)\over f(x)}$$

Do I need to prove this first?

Or can I just leave it as prerequisite knowledge before reading the paper?

**P.S. - ** I understand this isn't exactly a Maths question in a sense. But it is Maths related and it takes a Mathematician to answer.

Comment: What is your function $f$ ?

Comment: @jibounet - Just any differentiable function.

Comment: Then, the equality $\ln f(x) = \frac{ f'(x) }{x}$ does not make sense. Did you mean :

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln f(x) = \frac{ f'(x) }{ f(x) } $$

?

Comment: @jibounet - YES that's what I meant... an honest typing error, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Yeah I think OP probably made a typo/mistake. To the OP: as long as you can find a proof of that fact that doesn't use the relation $(e^x)'=e^x$, you would be avoiding circular reasoning and good to go (presumably). So I suppose your question comes down to whether or not such a proof exists.

Comment: It may depend on how you define $e$ and $\ln$...

Comment: @peterwhy - I define $e$ as being $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Big( 1 + {1\over n} \Big)^n$ .

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question depends on what you expect your readers to know in advance. Since you're writing about derivatives, they should know calculus.

Then the fact that $e^x$ is its own derivative is likely to be a better known prerequisite than the statement about logarithmic derivatives you want to use to prove it.

Comment: Ah I see... I suppose I'll write it as a prerequisite at the start of the paper so people know. It's aimed at First year university students and above.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't really proven anything. You have used something that needs proving, to "prove" that the derivative of $\mathrm e^x$ is itself. It's really just a circular argument.

I would suggest that you prove it from [first principles](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/metric/metric_public/differentiation/):

$$\mathrm f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \left(\frac{\mathrm f(x+h)-\mathrm f(x)}{h}\right)$$

In your case, $\mathrm f(x) = \mathrm e^x$ and so
\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\mathrm e^x &=& \lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{\mathrm e^{x+h}-\mathrm e^x}{h}\right) \\ \\
&=& \lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{(\mathrm e^{h}-1)\mathrm e^x}{h}\right) \\ \\
&=& \mathrm e^x \cdot \lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{\mathrm e^{h}-1}{h}\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}

To prove your statement from [first principles](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/metric/metric_public/differentiation/) you need only show that
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{\mathrm e^{h}-1}{h}\right)=1$$

Comment: Oh I know the proof, I was just unsure of how much I can assume people know already.

Comment: @MaxEchendu It depends on your audience. If they are at university then first principles is the way to go 100%. If they are at high school and are very bright then first principles is worth a try.

Comment: This might not be as "first principles" as you would hope. The definition and properties of $e^x$ for arbitrary real $x$ probably come from the exponential function, which *can* be defined as a particular solution to the differential equation $f'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: @BenMillwood All I used was the power law $a^{x+y} = a^x\cdot a^y$ for all constants $a>0$. To evaluate the limit, I used the fact that $\ln(\mathrm e) = 1$ and the definition
$$\mathrm{e}^r = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{r}{x}\right)^x$$

Comment: @FlybyNight: how do you prove the power law for (potentially) irrational exponents?

Comment: @BenMillwood This is a deep philosophical question. It is far more fundamental than the level of differentiation from first principles. It's a fundamental question from real analysis. *Personally*, I make sense of irrational powers as limits of sequences of rational powers. You could ask the same question in many different contexts. You could keep stripping every mathematical statement back a level. How do we know $1+1=2$? It took Whitehead & Russell more than 350 pages to prove that $1+1=2$. Most sane mathematicians assume certain properties of the real numbers and the associated operations.

Comment: @FlybyNight The problem is that among the assumptions that most "sane" mathematicians are happy to make is that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$. Certainly you can't use *that* assumption to prove the claim. So when you're purporting to prove a very basic principle, you have to make sure that the foundations you rest it on are not consequences of it, which can depend on your definitions and constructions. Your proof, dropped into the analysis course I did at university, would be circular: however, it sounds like you have a reasonable alternative in which it's not.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I agree with @EthanBolker's answer above.

With regards to the question of whether a proof of the fact exists without assuming the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, the answer is yes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Natural_Logarithm_Function

The equality follows from the chain rule, and hence depends on a proof that $$ {d \over dx} \ln x = {1 \over x}$$

One can prove this, for instance, using the fundamental theorem of calculus and the fact that the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln x$.

Comment: True. But this proof depends on a definition of the natural logarithm that gets you to its derivative without involving exponentiation. That's possible if you define the natural logarithm as the integral of $1/x$ (as in your proofwiki reference) but (to my mind) that's elegant but not natural.

Comment: I don't disagree, haha.